# How do we examine a particular job in GTM?

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, mumps, vistadb, gtm-database

Just as we have in Intersystem Cache D ^JOBEXAM to examine the jobs running in background or scheduled.

How can we do the same in GTM?

Do we have any command for the same. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $zinterrupt; and what triggers it: mupip intrpt. Normally it dumps a file on your GT.M start-up directory containing the process state via ZSHOW "*"; however, you can make $zinterrupt do any thing you want.

$ZINT documentation:
http://tinco.pair.com/bhaskar/gtm/doc/books/pg/UNIX_manual/ch08s35.html

A complex example of using $ZINT:
https://github.com/shabiel/random-vista-utilities/blob/master/ZSY.m

--Sam

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here.  In addition to what Sam has said, there is a code set, "^ZJOB" that is used in the VistA world.  I could get you copies of this if you wanted.